# Customer provided image for order

Tags: orders, image, upload

I'm looking for a feature or extension that would require a customer to upload an image as part of an order.

Searching around all I can find are extensions that let users upload alternative images for existing products.

Is there a core feature or extension that takes an image from a customer as part of their order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, core Magento doesn't have any feature like that out of the box. What those extensions might be doing is extending a very powerful core feature, Custom Options.  In essence, your products will have a custom option with them which will hold the path to the uploaded image file. Image upload will be needed to be handled separately. This way, customer's image gets somewhat attached to the order item. You'll also need to customize the cart page and order emails to show those custom images instead of the default one. This basically sums up the logic, if you can break it down like this, it's very probable that you'll find code for these small tasks very easily all over the Google.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't really know what to search for. Now I've been able to find [this article](http://www.host1plus.com/tutorials/cms-tutorials/magento/magento-administration/how-to-use-magento-custom-options-to-upload-file-in-the-product-page) quickly. Looks like I'm headed in the right direction!